# array.push() does not work when querying a database (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am quite new to Javascript so forgive me if I am not seeing something. I am trying to query a SQLite database and obtain float values of a particular column. I then want to add each row's value of that column to an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var latitudes = [];
var longitudes = [];
var altitudes = [];

var centerLat = 0;
var centerLon = 0;


let db = new sqlite3.Database('C:/sqlite/gpsdata.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the GPS database.');
});

db.each("SELECT * FROM GPSDATA", [], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    
    console.log(parseFloat(row.LATITUDE));
    latitudes.push(parseFloat(row.LATITUDE));
    latitudes.push(5);
  });

console.log(latitudes.length);


db.close((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Closed the database connection.');
});
```

The console outputs:

```
0
Connected to the GPS database.
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.852184
50.85218
50.85218
50.85218
50.85218
50.85218
50.85218
Closed the database connection.
```

As you can see I guess it's querying the database correctly, but pushing these values to the array doesn't seem to work. Even if I push a random value. the size remains 0. I feel like it's not working because I am not in the right scope or something. How can I work around this?

Comment: It works, you're just misunderstanding the order in which this all happens. This is asynchronous. Move your `console.log(latitudes.length);` inside the callback for `db.close` so that it can be executed **after** pushing the data inside the Array

Comment: In the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementeachparam--callback-complete) there is also a second `complete` callback specified for the `each` statement. "After all row callbacks were called, the completion callback will be called if present." Same basic concept as what @blex suggests.

Comment: @blex thank you very much